# Override MongoDb .NET CRUD methods

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, overriding, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to know if and how I can override the CRUD methods of a IMongoCollection instance.
This is my simplified MongoContext object.

```
public class MongoContext
{
    protected internal MongoClient client;
    protected internal IMongoDatabase database;

    public MongoContext(string connectionString, string databaseName)
    {
        client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<Event> Events
    {
        get { return database.GetCollection<Event>("Event"); }
    }
}
```

And here I am calling it:

```
 var mongoContext = new MongoContext("....", "EventDb");
 var newEvent = new Event() { EventName = "Event Foo" }
 mongoContext.Events.InsertOne(newEvent);
```

For every element for this collection I want to store the date of creation and the last day the element was modified.

```
public override void InsertOne(TDocument document, InsertOneOptions options = null, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
    document.DateCreation = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

How can I implement this ?

Comment: do it in the constructor of event and continue using standard mongo API calls

Comment: I want to implement something generic. In a real application I could have a lot of documents created from a lot of different places.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran in to this same issue a while ago.
And while I also tried overriding the original methods there is no easy way to do so.
However I managed to solve the problem by creating a base class like

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements(Inherited = true)]
public abstract class MongoBaseDocument
{
    public BsonObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [BsonIgnore]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsNewEntity => Id == null || Id == BsonObjectId.Empty;
}
```

And made the other mongo related classes inherit it as

```
public class MongoObject : MongoBaseDocument
```

This solved the problem and allows for adding more functionality if required.